# MVC RouteConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've set up an MVC project, it works perfectly. But I upgraded with a new controller, added some new views, nothing special... The web page works almost perfect when online except that it can't find my new views online.

I really don't know why, because it works in all debug modes in localhost on my machine, but not when published, I did publish the entire solution.

I've also noticed that I can't add new pages to my working home-controller either, I can only edit the ones that I have.

I checked RouteConfig and there are only the default basic settings

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I've created a new controller called **Questionnaires**, do I have to add this to RouteConfig to make it run online?

Browser address:

```
www.<address>.com/home/OneView
```

But with the new Views I want this for the new pages:

```
www.<address>.com/Questionnaires/Mixer
```

When browsing to the address I receive this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Questionnaires/Mixers
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? That's important information to include.

Comment: Only error I get is this from the browser: Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. 404...

Comment: *Any time* you have an exception in your application related to your question, include the exception message and stack trace, and any related source code. Edit that information into the question, and realize that people shouldn't have to prompt you for that information, you should just include it.

Comment: You're right, I'm so sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You said it can't find your views, but routing isn't concerned with views. It's concerned with mapping requests to a controller and action method. The action method is what returns the view. If you created a new controller called `QuestionnairesController`, then you should be able to access it at `/Questionnaires`. And since that URL doesn't specify an action method, it will by default (because of your configured route defaults) look for an action method named `Index`.

If you want to access the Mixer action method in the QuestionnairesControllers at `/Questionnaires/Mixer`, that should work fine based on the routing you showed us.

When you do `return View();` in your `Mixer` action method, it will by default look for a view at `~/Views/Questionnaires/Mixer.csthml` (among several other locations, but that's where you most commonly put it).

Comment: Yes.... I've also noticed that if I add new Views to the "Home-folder" they can't be found either. I've updated HomeController with the classic ActionResult block... For the moment I can only update my files, not add any new files like I mentioned before. I can upload/publish any files, they are at the server (but not found by the browser), all files with the correct code (it works offline), but not online.

Comment: @Varg Like I said already, you need to put the exception information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit embarrassing, but I did not notice that i published my project in Debug mode, set to Release solved the problems. Never missed this before.

Sorry about all this, have mercy...

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Change it back to debug and redeploy. It will probably still work. Most likely your original publish didn't get all the files up onto the server, hence the 404.

Comment: I'll try that the next time. The web page is an online system that have many visitors daily. Also the web page is completed for the moment, so I'll wait for the next update... But I'll keep that in mind. Thank you very much @mason